# Loading Animation in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dialog-window, popup, monitoring

I'm using `Manipulate` together with `CreateDialog` to run a `ListPlot` whenever I click on a simulation button. That is, evaluation within `Manipulate` only occurs when I want to. Specifically, I have the code

```
s = {None};
Button["Start",
 f[aa_, oo_, pp_] := CreateDialog[Column[{
     Manipulate[
      frame = Refresh[ListPlot[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, a]], 
        Sequence @@ s],
      Control[{{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 100000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
      Button["Simulate", s = {}; s = {None}]]
     }], Modal -> True, WindowTitle -> "Simulation"];
 f[Unevaluated@a, Unevaluated@o, Unevaluated@p]]
```

which after clicking 'Start', leads to the popup window

[image]

Changing the values `a` does not automatically updates the plot, only when I click on `Simulate`.

For higher values of the parameter (`a=100000`, for example), plotting takes a bit longer and since I'm on a `CreateDialog` environment, the only indicator of ongoing evaluation is the following (I'm using Windows 10)

[image]

I wonder if it's possible to implement a small "loading" animation or progress indicator in the popup window itself. For example, replace the plot by that while it's being evaluated and inactivate the 'Simulate' button.

I am aware of `Monitor` and `ProgressIndicator`, but I can't seem to make it work in the `CreateDialog` environment. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Does it need to be something animated or could you replace the plot with a static message like "Please wait"? 2. Is the simulation button essential or are you just trying to avoid continuous updates while the slider is being moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) instead of `Manipulate`

Also, just for fun, I decided to overkill this problem to demonstrate how this kind of thing can be done extensibly and flexibly.

```
Options[MySimulation] =
  {
   "RangeMin" -> 1,
   "RangeMax" -> 100,
   "PointsMin" -> 0,
   "PointsMax" -> 100000
   };
Format[MySimulation[Dynamic[state_Symbol], ops : OptionsPattern[]]] :=

  Interpretation[
   DynamicModule[
    {
     frame, 
     simulate,
     plot,
     a,
     display,
     min = OptionValue[MySimulation, {ops}, "RangeMin"], 
     max = OptionValue[MySimulation, {ops}, "RangeMax"],
     pmin = OptionValue[MySimulation, {ops}, "PointsMin"],
     pmax = OptionValue[MySimulation, {ops}, "PointsMax"]
     },
    Panel[
     Grid[
      {
       {"a", Manipulator[Dynamic[state["Value"]], {pmin, pmax}]},
       {Button["Simulate", simulate[state["Value"]], Method -> "Queued"], 
        SpanFromLeft},
       {Panel[Dynamic[display], Background -> White], SpanFromLeft}
       }
      ]
     ],
    Initialization :> {
      If[! AssociationQ@state,
       state = <|"Value" -> 1|>;
       ],
      simulate[a_] :=
       (
        display =
         Pane[
          Row@{"Calculating", ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Ellipsis"]},
          ImageSize -> {500, 500/GoldenRatio}
          ];
        Pause[1];
        state["Data"] = RandomInteger[{min, max}, a];
        display = plot[state["Data"]];
        ),
      plot[data_] :=
       ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> 500],
      If[MissingQ@state["Data"], 
       simulate[state["Value"]]
       ]
      }
    ],
   MySimulation[Dynamic[state], ops]
   ];
MySimulation[] :=
 With[{state = Unique[`MySimulation`state]}, 
  SetAttributes[state, Temporary];
  MySimulation[Dynamic[state]]
  ]
```

In this I 1) bind my data to a `state` symbol which I stores all the simulation state 2) I make sure that gets passed through to a simulation object 3) this object displays as the simulation control, but retains a convenient `InputForm` and 4) I make sure to feed in my options in a nice way.

Lots of things you can build off of this, but I think it's a cute template if you don't do this kind of thing often.

Here's a demo:

```
MySimulation[]
```

[image]

```
% // InputForm

MySimulation[Dynamic[Global`MySimulation`state$223319]]

Global`MySimulation`state$223319//Short

<|Value->54200.,Data->{68,98,90,56,76,59,59,86,<<54184>>,10,57,66,52,68,74,99,19}|>
```

And when you press the button it "thinks" for a second and looks like:

[image]